# PHP PDO can't delete record

Tags: php, pdo

I'm having a bit of a problem with PDO deleting a record from the database.

It just returns false, and I can't seem to see why, can anyone help?
The code:

```
$db = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server='.DB_HOST.';Database='.DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
$query = $db->prepare('DELETE * FROM '.$table.' WHERE id = :id');
$query->bindValue(':id', $id);
$query->execute();
```

I've also tried:

```
$db = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server='.DB_HOST.';Database='.DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
$db->exec('DELETE * FROM '.$table.' WHERE id = '.$id);
```

And I know the user from the DB has permissions to delete because I can run the query with success in the SQL client.

Any ideas?

Thanks :)

Comment: I'm curious about how you get this `$table` var. It could be a security hole.

Comment: @brewal I was thinking the same - hopefully he's got it wrapped in `mysqli_real_escape_string` at the very least

Comment: I think I would whitelist some table names in an array and just test it with `in_array()` function.

Comment: The $table and $id are passed by me, not from the user. This belongs to a simple CRUD Class that I'm creating, I just posted the relevant parts.

Comment: Ok, that was just in case ;)

Comment: It's something like this "$db->store('category', array('title'=>'R&D', 'tag'=>'rd', 'ord'=>998));"

Comment: Sorry, wrong one :) this is the one "$db->trash('category', 171);"

Comment: @iamgory actually I'm just using the simple PDO functions bindValue() to bind the values, do you recommend to pass through mysqli_real_escape_string first? Because I thought it wouldn't be necessary with the prepare() of PDO. But I'm new to all of this and always appreciate help from you guys :)

Comment: We're just referencing `$table`, `$id` is fine :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first example is fine, bar one error

```
$db = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server='.DB_HOST.';Database='.DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
$query = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM '.$table.' WHERE id = :id');
$query->bindValue(':id', $id);
$query->execute();
```

You don't need a * in a simple delete statement.

FYI, `rowCount()` will work well for confirming the delete worked, as follows:

```
$countDel = $query->rowCount();
if ($countDel == 0) {
echo "No rows deleted";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
DELETE FROM $table WHERE id = $id
```

- there is no  `*` in the `DELETE` statement

Go here for some easy [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp).

Comment: You might want to link to some more reliable documentation,w3schools is right only by mistake.

Comment: Its easy place to start. I try not to give very complicated answer links to ppl that are just starting theirs adventure with databases. I think this would be bad. 1st allow them to know basics, then they will try to get more knowledge with more demands for themselves.